# Use Valgrind on shared library that is closed before the app exits

Tags: c, debugging, memory-leaks, valgrind

How to find memory leaks in shared library (.so) that is loaded dynamically in a third party app, for which the code is not available (but has been built with debug info)? The problem is probably that the shared library is dlclose'd before the exit of the application and Valgrind no longer has the debug information of the application and reports the addresses of memory leaks as question marks.

Currently have tried the following:

1. Built the project with debug info using both clang and gcc
   compilers
2. LD_PRELOAD the shared library before running the application

Is there anything that can be done so that Valgrind can detect the debug symbols?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extract from valgrind 3.14 NEWS:

> - The new option --keep-debuginfo=no|yes (default no) can be used to retain   debug info for unloaded code.  This allows saved stack traces
>     (e.g. for   memory leaks) to include file/line info for code that has
>     been dlclose'd (or   similar).  See the user manual for more
>     information and known limitations.

So, just using --keep-debuginfo=yes should show the proper stacktraces for the leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the correct flags for the linker on gcc, the shared library is forced to stay loaded until the application exits. This option is called:

```
-z nodelete
```

Sample flags for building with gcc:

```
gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall -z nodelete
```

and for CMAKE:

```
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS, "-z nodelete")
```

The above have only been tested with gcc.